# Tablet always loading portrait layout

Tags: android, android-layout

I have 2 layouts one for phones and tablets in portrait the other for tablets in landscape. The issue is that the landscape view is always loaded on the tablet (Samsung tab 3).
I have the following buckets defined

```
layout
layout-xlarge-land
layout-xlarge-port
```

The layout and layout-xlarge-port have the same xml layout and the land has a different one. But the tablet always loads the landscape one how come?

Answer (score 0):

Android studio was caching my xmls did a clean and it worked